# Cannot reach service fabric service

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I create a service fabric application on my local development machine with 3 statless services, one of the service (Service1) has an endpoint with a static port assigned , Service is a .net core web api hosted using kestrel

After deploying the application to my local cluster , I am not able to acess this service using the following URL

http://localhost:8641/api/values

but I can access it using the reverse proxy url

http://localhost:19081/ServiceFabricApplicationName/Service1/api/values

Any ides why I cannot reach the service with first url ?

Comment: Can you share `ApplicationManifest.xml`? Also do you see your endpoint in Service Fabric Explorer?

Comment: @OlegKarasik Thank you very much .I fixed the problem. the port was not opened on my machine , I just used another one